# Magento 2 free shipping method not showing

Tags: magento-2.1, checkout, shipping, shipping-methods

I only set my shipping method to free shipping and only for one specific country like this:

[image]

but the problem is this shipping method won't appear if the country value already selected first when the checkout page load, but if i refresh the page the free shipping method will appear, but if i change the country to another country and change back to the original country the shipping method won't appear unless i don't fill the postal code.

with postal code :

[image]

without postal code:

[image]

Comment: What is your default country in Admin >> Stores >> Configuration >> General >> General >> Country Options >> Default Country ?

Comment: @SHPatel Australia

Comment: have u check the log files?

Comment: @AmitBera yes there's no error

Comment: Do you get any console log errors?

Comment: What is Magento version you're using?
I tried to replicate your issue on my 2.1.5 but all seems work fine.

Comment: @WaPoNe mine is 2.1.1

Comment: Why don't you upgrade your Magento instance to 2.1.6 (the last one) version? It may depend on the version.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure you have found a solution already but this is for others that may come across the same issue.

I was playing around with table rate shipping and had changed the store view Default Config to Main Website in order to upload the shipping rate csv file. I must have changed the free shipping rate then from enabled Yes to No.

Click system value on Free shipping to fix the issue.